# Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain in my Flutter project

Tags: flutter, gradle, build, apk

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           471ms
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

I want to build android app from my flutter project but when i write this

```
-flutter build apk --release
```

in my cmd i got this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           471ms
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```